# Lifting State with hooks (from a mapped array)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm confused about how I'm supposed to raise events from a child component using hooks (or stateless components rather).  Maybe I'm thinking too much.  Or not enough!  I have built a simple example illustrating my confusion.

Say we have a parent component with some data

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Parent = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      thing: 1,
      info: "this is thing 1"
    },
    {
      thing: 2,
      info: "this is thing 1"
    },
    {
      thing: 3,
      info: "this is thing 3"
    }
  ];

  function handleClick(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }

  return (
    <div> 
    <h1> This is the Parent </h1> 
    <Child data={data} onShowClick={handleClick} /> 
    </div>
  )
};
```

And child components created from mapping through the data

```
const Child = (data, {onShowClick}) => {
  return (
    <ul> 
      { data.data.map(item => {return (
        <li key={item.thing}>{item.info}
        <button onClick={() => onShowClick}>Click</button>  
        </li>
      )})}
    </ul> 
  )
}
```

If this was all found in the same component I would do something like

```
onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
```

But you can't pass an argument with a prop.

```
onClick={(item) => onShowClick}
// Or
onClick={onShowClick(item)}
```

Maybe hooks are confusing me.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy buddy. check below code. I just made some changes in you code.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const data = [
        {
            thing: 1,
            info: "this is thing 1"
        },
        {
            thing: 2,
            info: "this is thing 2"
        },
        {
            thing: 3,
            info: "this is thing 3"
        }
    ];

    const handleClick = (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> This is the Parent </h1>
            <Child data={data} onShowClick={handleClick} />
        </div>
    )
};

const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.data.map(item => {
                return (
                    <li key={item.thing}>{item.info}
                        <button onClick={() => props.onShowClick(item)}>Click</button>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is the closest to an answer - I had actually de-structured props in the child function, but it works if I pass only props to the child arrow function.  I don't know if I understand why it works when passing just props as opposed to (data, {onShowClick})

Thanks!

Comment: You just taught me how to move state between different components. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `hooks`.

You should check the documentation on how to pass arguments to event handlers:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

This is the example from the documentation.

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
```

But since you do not need `e`, you just going to pass `item`

```
{
  data.data.map(item => (
    <li key={item.thing}>{item.info}
      <button onClick={() => onShowClick(item)}>Click</button>
    </li>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to combine the 2.

```
onClick={(item) => onShowClick(item)}
```

You also need to add `this` when you send the function to the child or make it a constant outside the Parent, `onShowClick={this.handleClick}`

Comment: No luck. Also played around with placing a handler in the child function in order to pass an argument to it, but then you run into the same problem of where you pass the item argument

Comment: Are you getting the item in the closure? What happens if you try `onClick={(item) => { console.log('clicked: ', item); onShowClick(item):}}` ?

Comment: This returns null values and some warnings "This synthetic event is reused for performance

Comment: I think the use of 'this' is really the essence of the problem.  In classes, 'this' makes sense, but when using hooks we are basically using functional components without the 'this' keyword to bind things.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={() => onShowClick}` is a mistake, `onShowClick` function isn't called.

If a value from enclosing scope needs to be used, it is:

```
  { data.data.map(item => (
    <li key={item.thing}>{item.info}
    <button onClick={() => onShowClick(item)}>Click</button>  
    </li>
  ))}
```